# Reading Data from ttl rs485 converter In Python

Tags: python, pyserial, rs485

I was trying to read data from smart power meter using ttl rs485 converter and  ft232 serial converter connected to PC. I've tried to read the data from serial port using the Pyserial python module and used the code below but the only output I've got was ("b, "b, ",b), I was wondering if there is any mistake in my code!
Thanks.

The code I used

```
    import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port= 'COM5',
    baudrate= 9600,

    parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,

    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,

    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout= 2 
)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr, "Please wait" )
print('COM5 is now Open!')
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()

while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    print(data)
```

The output I got

```
connected to: COM5 Please wait
COM5 is now Open!
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
```

Comment: You have been reading empty lines. Did you check that the converter works with a terminal program?

Comment: Yeah I did, and it is not working, but the converter is working as I have used it before.

Comment: is there anyway I can read the data from the power meter through rs485 and ft232 serial converter???

Answer (score 0):

I returned data with this after I added 0xff to `ser.readline()`:

```py
while True:
    data = ser.readline(0xff)
```